# How do I get database information after running pg_connect?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have some code that runs a function and within it executes pg_connect.

```
$db = pg_connect("$dsn");
```

Is it possible to retrieve the database information from the $db variable, specifically the database name?  If I run a var_dump on $db I get:

```
resource(18) of type (pgsql link)
```

Comment: "Is it possible to retrieve the database information from the $db variable" -no

Comment: The database name is in your connection string. Without this name, it's impossible to connect to this database. So why asking for something you already know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is to use the PHP function that was specifically developed for this purpose:

```
$db_name = pg_dbname($db);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-dbname.php

This saves you the `SELECT`.

Comment: Hah! It didn't even occur to me to look!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply run a command on the database you've connected to that asks for its name; as [documented in the Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html), the relevant query would be:

```
SELECT current_database() as database_name;
```

(I will assume you know how to run an SQL query using your $db variable, so won't bother with PHP samples.)